# Dynamic Table names in hive

Tags: sql, hive, macros

I am trying to create a table which has a dynamic name based on some logic.

Result I need: table name as Table_202303

Input:
Set yrmo = date_format(add_months(date_format(current_date, 'yyyy-MM-01',-5), 'yyyyMM');

create table dB.Table_${hiveconf:yrmo} as.......
;

I get an error on this. I am not sure if set function works this way. I have tried hiveconf, hivevar @yrmo to check if anything works but nothing works for this.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you write the ddl. Maybe in hive-cli or shell?

If you write sql in shell, you can use `date -d +%Y%m%d` to create datetime, then use hive -e "create table xxx_${your_datetime}"